# Duplicating a nested set of folders in bash/fish

Tags: bash, duplicates, copy

I have a folder full of other folders.  Within each of these folders, there also exists another folder that I want to duplicate, but with a new name (same for all copies).

For example:

```
├── application
│   └── foo
│        └── bar
│             └── redacted.txt
│
├── something_different
│   └── foo
│        └── bar
│             └── RobotoMono.ttf
```

So every top level folder has a "foo/bar/" folder.  I'd like to clone the "bar" folder (and the contents) so there is a "bar2" folder under each "foo" folder.
Then it would look like this:

```
├── application
│   └── foo
│        └── bar
│             └── redacted.txt
│        └── bar2
│             └── redacted.txt
│
├── something_different
│   └── foo
│        └── bar
│             └── RobotoMono.ttf
│        └── bar2
│             └── RobotoMono.ttf
```

I can successfully get the list with "find".  Here is what I have tried:

```
find . -name bar -exec cp -r '{}' '{}'/bar2 \;

find . -name bar | xargs cp -r /bar2
```

And of course theses don't work and leave some nice looping that was fun to clean up.  Thank you for reading and explaining what I'm doing incorrectly, or if I'm even close to what I should be doing.

Comment: Generally speaking, it is really helpful to include the actual error messages that are emitted by the script and/or the shell. They may appear to contain little meaning, but they  will always point to the underlying problem.

Comment: @theruss the first example loops creating subdirectories until the names are too long.

the second example states:
`cp: /bar2: No such file or directory.`

Answer (score 0):

First of all the single quotes around the parentheses will give you a string not the actual target (the directory) that you want. Removing these and copying to one level above "bar" seems to work (bash):

```
#> mkdir -p application/foo/bar && touch application/foo/bar/redacted.txt 
#> find application -name bar -exec cp -r {} {}/../bar2 \;
#> ls -l application/foo/ | awk '{ print $NF }'
./
../
bar/
bar2/
#> ls -l application/foo/bar2/ | awk '{ print $NF }'
./
../
redacted.txt
```

Comment: Do not parse the output of ls even with awk.

Comment: I should add that the use of awk was for display purposes _only_

Comment: Thank you.  This is the quick I'm looking for to get this done for now.  It is nice to know I wasn't /too/ far off from what I needed. I tried to upvote, but don't have enough points for it to show.

Comment: You should at least be able to accept the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
find . \
  -path '.*/foo/bar' \
  -type d \
  -exec sh -c 'p="${0%/*}"; n="${0##*/}"; cp -rp -- "$p/$n" "$p/${n}2"' {} \;
```

- `-exec sh -c` Executes the inline shell script

Here is the content of the inline shell script with added comments:

```sh
# Extract the path before /bar from argument 0
p="${0%/*}"

# Extract the trailing name bar or anything else from argument 0
n="${0##*/}"

# Perform a recursive copy with preserved permissions
# from the source to the destination with suffix2
cp -rp -- "$p/$n" "$p/${n}2"
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  This is the stuff I want to learn to be able to do more advanced stuff with.  The explanations really help.  I tried to upvote, but don't have enough points for it to show.

Comment: @EmCeeNutt you can accept the answer, no point required for this.